# How to define multiple distinct controllers in Grails 2 filter?

Tags: grails, grails-filters

Is it possible to define multiple distinct controller in a Grails 2 web application filter? For example, something like:

```
def filters = {
    someFilterMethod(controller: 'controller1 controller2 ...', action: '*') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Otherwise, is there a way to specify to not include the main index.gsp in the filter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the pipe symbol:

```
def filters = {
   someFilterMethod(controller: 'controller1|controller2|...', action: '*') {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: @Burt Beckwith - Nope, this is pretty much on the money. Leave it to Burt. By the way, your Grails tutorials have been helpful more than a few times :)

Comment: How would you do this for different actions? ie, Controller1 has action A and Controller2 has action b.

Answer (score 4):

If you can define a rule that matches index.gsp, then you can define a rule that matches everything but index.gsp by adding `invert: true`. I guess something like this should do it:

```
def filters = {
    someFilterMethod(uri: '/', invert: 'true') {

    }
}
```

It seems like the following should also work:

```
def filters = {
    someFilterMethod(uriExclude: '/') {

    }
}
```

You can provide a regex instead of a literal path, so if you also need to exclude '/index' as well, then you just need to replace '/' with a regex that matches '/' and '/index'. My regex skills are rusty, but something like this should do it:

```
def filters = {
    someFilterMethod(uriExclude: '/(index)?', regex: true) {

    }
}
```

### Warning

I haven't tested any of the code above, so caveat emptor!

Answer (score 1):

You could include logic within the filter like

```
if (controllerName == "controller1" || controllerName == "controller2") {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Sure you can do *that*, I was looking for a more elegant way.

Comment: Yeah, but handling multiple controllers in filter like "(controller1|controller2)", means later on you need to make a filter that excludes those controllers, making it just really messy.