# Prevent login filter to filter web service url

Tags: java, spring, grails, filter, grails-filters

I have JAX-RS service at `api/interface/data` and I have used login filter in my web-app that fiters all url and makes sure user is logged in. 
Login filter code is:

```
all(controller:'site',invert:true) {
            before = {
                if (session.getAttribute("currentUserId")==null) {
                    redirect(controller:"site",action:"index")
                    return false
                }
            }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I request my web service through any rest client is redirect me as I am not logged in into session.
I 've tried to use `all(controller:'site|api',invert:true)` but it didn't work.

Comment: Your filter applies to anything that doesn't come from the controller site so api/interface/data would fall under that. Are you trying to apply that filter to all of your site EXCEPT api/interface/data? If so then you should use all(uri: '/api/**', invert: true)

Comment: You may want to play with uri, uriExclude and regex options in filter rule, here is some [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941249/how-to-define-mutliple-distinct-controllers-in-grails-2-filter).