# Grails security filter doesn't work with 2 controllers

Tags: security, grails, groovy

I'm using grails 2.4.3, created a security filter. I had 3 controller in my project name: admin, login and report. So I added following to the filter:

```
def filters = {
        all(controller: 'Admin', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (!session.company) {
                    redirect(controller: 'login', action: 'auth')
                    return false
                }
            }
            after = { Map model ->

            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->

            }
        }
    }
```

I mean that any actions from admin controller, if `!session.company`, a page will be redirected into the auth action in a login controller.

Now I'd like to add a controller report into this filter, how do I do that? I tried `all(controller: ['Admin', 'Report'], action: '*')` but it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use pipe symbol to add multiple controllers, like

```
def filters = {
    all(controller: 'Admin|Report', action: '*') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Ref# [How to define mutliple distinct controllers in Grails 2 filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941249/how-to-define-mutliple-distinct-controllers-in-grails-2-filter)

Comment: Thanks, it's really helpful, I think about it before but I type wrong syntax. I tried `Report` but it supports to be `report`. Anyway thanks bro. Good day.